# Installing Ubuntu using Pendrive

Tags: ubuntu

I am new to Linux, so I need clarification. I Installed Ubuntu using pen drive on my PC and I installed new software like Qt creator. I am doing some work on Qt and after finishing my work I eject the pen drive. Am I able to continue my work at a later date if I use a pen drive to boot the OS?

Comment: Unless you save your work to pen drive it won't be stored on your system, since the system is being run from portable drive.

Comment: Ok.For Example If i am Working on a Project in Qt Creator and I need to install some API's  for that Project.As you said i need to save the project files to my pendrive.That's fine.But what about the Installed API's which is support for my project?are they still present?

Comment: Any software you install can be saved on the USB. You can also simply run on on memory, which will be removed when you shutdown your computer.

Comment: Fine,Suppose if i installed it from Ubuntu software center means can i able to use later?

Comment: Afraid I am not entirely sure from the software centre. You would have to test it and see what happens.